# I actually doesn't understand why {%if%} {%else%} doesn't work there. I just need to render this if author and username are equal

Tags: django

Actually, I am new in Django so I don't understand why if else statement doesn't work here. Is there anything super wrong with this code?

```
{%extends 'main/base.html'%}

{%block title%}
{{ title  }}
{%endblock%}


{%block content%}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>{{user.first_name}}</h2>
    <p>{{user.second_name}}</p>
    <div class="col">
        {%for recel in receipts%}
            {%if recel.author is user.username%}
                <h2>Receipt: {{recel.title}}</h2>
                <h4>Doctor: {{recel.author}}</h4>
            {%else%}
                <span></span>
            {%endif%}
         {%endfor%}
    </div>
</div>

{%endblock%}
```

Comment: `is` checks if they are the same object. You want to check for equality, which is `==`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is) It's not [DTL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/) (the framework Django is using to generate the HTML pages), but it's similar to python in many aspects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your using django's authentication.

replace:

```
{% if recel.author is request.user %}
```

with:

```
{%if recel.author is user.username%}
```

Answer (score 0):

`is` checks if the objects are the same object. You want to check for equality (if the objects have same value), which is done using `==`.

```
{%if recel.author == user.username%}
    {%if recel.author is user.username%}
        <h2>Receipt: {{recel.title}}</h2>
        <h4>Doctor: {{recel.author}}</h4>
    {%else%}
        <span></span>
    {%endif%}
{%endfor%}
```

Django's Template Language ([DTL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/)) is similar to python in many aspects, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is) explains in greater depth about the differences between `is` and `==`.